# Automated culling of accounts based on ldap

Tags: oracle, ldap

I want to make a tool that disables users in a database that don't exist anymore in an LDAP server. According to the suggestion of @Connor I would like to create a script on Oracle SQL Developer that makes a query against ldap server (lets say myldap.server.com) for all users ids and store this result on an external oracle table. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utopia would be single sign-on, ie, all your databases reference the LDAP repository directly, thus rendering the cleanup issue non-existent.

In the absence of that opportunity, you could something like a preprocessor script in an external table definition that performs a LDAP query of usernames, and returns that back via the external table definition.  (Let's call this external table LDAP_ACCTS).

Then it would be just a simple join between DBA_USERS and LDAP_ACCTS to derive differences and issue the appropriate 'alter user account lock' and/or 'drop user cascade' commands.

Comment: Your suggestion was very good. I'm not an expert on databases but I liked it very much. Thank you Connor!